# Choose default program to where the file was created

Tags: finder

I have a slight annoyance related to default programs. I use [Inscape](https://inkscape.org/) per default to deal with `.svg`-files in general, but at times use [Stylus labs Write](http://www.styluslabs.com/) for handwritten, digital notes. The latter use some sort of `HTML+svg`-file combination stored as `.svgz`-files, hence any Write-file per default opens in Incscape – although those files can't be opened and just yield an error message. Preferably, the Write-files should be opened in, well, Write (usually just from Finder). I'm not prepared to change the default program to Write for all `.svg`-files though.

One "obvious" solution is to manually change the default program for a newly created Write-file to be, you guessed it, Write. But I often forget and get a tiny bit annoyed the next time I open it and it starts Incscape.

I could use the approach of the second answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302607/always-open-pdfs-from-one-path-with-a-non-default-program), but these Write-files appear in many different places so it is not an optimal solution. Perhaps one could tweak the code to apply to all folders with a specific name? I would be prepared to have a folder structure so that all (or at least most) Write-file lies in a folder with a particular name (I mean, not all Write files in one folder, just in different folders with the same name).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this problem could be solved? The dream would be that the files created with Write are recognized as such, and that Finder automatically detects this and opens them with the correct program, and reverts to Inscape for all other `.svg`-files – I have no clue how one would manage that though.

Comment: Do all these files have the same suffix (.svg), or are there different ones for Inscape (.svg) and Write (.svgz)? If the have the same suffix, is there another way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: .svgz is a *compressed* .svg file.  As far as I know, Illustrator and Inkscape *can* read these files by default.  The issue you might be having is from the Note app not adhering  to the svg standard

Comment: Also, I’ve seen this question before (not svg specifically though) and you can’t differentiate opening files based on folder location.

Comment: @allan Well, I can image a little application as a default application for .svg/.svgz which forwards to Inscape or Write depending on a set of rules. Similar to https://underpassapp.com/LinkUnshortener/, but for suffixes instead of URLs.

Comment: Well, looking into it (there's not much documentation available) there's an entry in a FAQ that states "Write's native document format is HTML with embedded SVG", hence the problem with opening it in Incscape. There seems to be a workaround for these to be opened in Incscape by manually changing .svgz to .svg.gz, unzipping and then opening, but it's not really of help – I'm not that interested in opening these files in Incscape...

Comment: @Allan, are you sure of that? The linked question seems to have suggested solutions, although no accepted answer. I'll try it out, and see if I can get something towards a solution...

Comment: I’m referring to LaunchServices.  There’s no way for it to differentiate opening an app based on location.  As for 3rd party solutions and/or AppleScript functions, I’m not referring to that.